# How can I process a variable string with escape characters in it in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

In my C# code I need, sometimes, to process strings (Mostly XML strings) of the following format: 
Example:

```
string str = "<ObjectConnectionSettings><ContextFields><ContextField Name="Server" Type="Text" Value="{$Profile.Server}" />";
```

The first double quote in context breaks the string pattern what leads to compile errors.

What is the best workaround for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes with a backslash like this `"A string with\"quotes\""`

Comment: You can also use @. eg @"A string with ""quotes""."

Comment: Escape quotes works only when you can define the string manually, I don't know how to add/insert escape characters at the right place in runtime...

Comment: The @"" doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Another option: you can use single quotes for attributes. `Name='Server'`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to Escape the double quote you do not want the compiler to pick up:

```
string str = "<ObjectConnectionSettings><ContextFields><ContextField Name=\"Server\" Type=\"Text\" Value=\"{$Profile.Server}\" />";
```

That way the compile will know not the accidentally do stuff with them. But there will still be double-quotes at runtime, when this string is evaluated by somebody elses Database Access code.

Comment: Thank you for you reply,
The Escape '\' character can indeed be used with predefined strings, but what if you get such string as input in runtime?

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly. You showed an example with a string literal leading to compile errors because it contains an unescaped quote. Dealing with run-time strings containing special characters isn't going to produce compile errors, so that seems a completely different problem.

Comment: @Arthur As Michael Kay said, now you are talking about a **completely** different thing.